# ImportError: No module named ceph_argparse

Tags: python, centos, ceph

I'am trying to run `ceph` command but I get the error

```
$ ceph
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ceph", line 100, in <module>
    from ceph_argparse import \
ImportError: No module named ceph_argparse
```

I found this link http://tracker.ceph.com/issues/11388

But `/dist-packages/ceph_argparse.py` doesn't exit in my `/usr/lib/python2.7`

I working on CentOS7 and I install `ceph` by

```
./autogen.sh 
./configure 
make 
make install
```

and follow this link http://ceph.com/docs/master/install/manual-deployment/

Comment: How did you install ceph? Can you locate ceph_argparse.py on your host?

Comment: I install ceph by
`./autogen.sh`
`./configure`
`make`
`make install` and follow this link http://ceph.com/docs/master/install/manual-deployment/
I found ceph_argparse.py at ceph/src/pybind/ceph_argparse.py

Comment: It should be installed to some other system path. Anyway, you can point PYTHONPATH to the place where ceph_argparse.py is located as a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to get all of require package before install ceph

following this link >> http://ceph.com/docs/master/install/get-packages/

Comment: Link is dead. This is why [link-only answers are discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/236527)

Answer (score 0):

I meet same problem

```
bash-5.0# ceph -s
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/ceph", line 146, in <module>
from ceph_argparse import \
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ceph_argparse'
```

Last I found my python version is default python3.7,but I install python2.7 ceph-common, the cpeh_argparse is not in **/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages**,but it is in **/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages**

- So make sure your ceph_argparse is in the corresponding python package

`ll /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages |grep ceph_argparse`

`ll /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages |grep ceph_argparse`